# Ghostscript compress pdf image transparency issues

Tags: pdf, optimization, transparency, ghostscript

Using Ghostscript 9.15 we execute this code for compression:

```
gs -o in.pdf -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dDownsampleColorImages=true 
             -dDownsampleGrayImages=true -dDownsampleMonoImages=true 
             -dColorImageResolution=144 -dGrayImageResolution=144 
             -dMonoImageResolution=144 -dColorImageDownsampleThreshold=1.0 
             -dGrayImageDownsampleThreshold=1.0 -dMonoImageDownsampleThreshold=1.0 
             -dNumRenderingThreads=8 -dBandHeight=100 -dBandBufferSpace=500000000 
             -sBandListStorage=memory out.pdf
```

But we have a problem with PNG with transparency and images with gradient transparency.

Example:

Before:  https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nio7x.png

After: https://i.stack.imgur.com/A43cA.png

There is some param to get rid of this issue only for transparent images?

Thank you!

Comment: You cannot have a PNG in a PDF file and I'm not clear on what you mean by 'images with gradient transparency'. From the bitmaps you've posted it looks like what you are complaining about is dropouts in images due to the image being downsampled, but its probably going to be a lot easier to discuss this if you post a (simple!) example to a public URL. In passing, the following parameters are only for rendering devices and so have no effect with pdfwrite: -dNumRenderingThreads, -dBandHeight, -dBandBufferSpace, -sBandListStorage.

Comment: You're totally right, I supposed that was PNG file as it have transparency. The problem is exactly as you described, the downsampling causes the dropouts in this image (but only this one, because I suppose it have opacity). I can't find a good solution for this for now, I'll keep looking for!

Comment: You could try using the /Bicubic downsample filter, but the results will be very highly dependent on the actual amount of downsampling going on. Bear in mind that Ghostscript isn't an image editing/manipulation package, it doesn't implement any really clever stuff for this, just what's needed for printing really.